# Camel Splitter, what is it worth if at the end messages are aggregated again?

Tags: split, apache-camel

Say you have this route :

```
from("direct:processOrders")
.process(new MultipleOrdersProcessor())
.to("direct:done")
```

MultipleOrdersProcessor loops through the orders and does "things"

What would be the benefit of using a splitter and having a SingleOrderProcessor instead of MultipleOrdersProcessor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two benefits

1. If one of the "orders" fails, it would not necessarily fail your
   entire exchange if they had been split into multiple messages.
2. It    may be easier to unit test a SingleOrderProcessor function using an
   automated tool.

Answer (score 2):

One immediate benefit is the ability to process orders in parallel, provided the use case fits parallel processing.
In case of MultipleOrdersProcessor a custom implementation is required for parallel processing.